# Skype for Business 2016

Tags: skype, skype-for-business

Anyone know a simple explanation why a Skype for Business user who is on a one-to-one video call cannot add another participant?

Nor can the other person on the video call?

Comment: Because your infrastructure is having issues or you disabled it by policy.

Comment: Please specify if your correspondent is also using Skype for Business or not. I think this makes a difference.